# Why is nodemon ignoring my /src file in angular

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Im using WSL2 and Docker.

**docker-compose :**

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        build: ./web
        command: sh -c "yarn; yarn run build && yarn start"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        working_dir: /usr/src/web
        volumes:
            - ./web:/usr/src/web:cached
```

**DockerFile:**

```
FROM node:14

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/web && chown -R node:node /usr/src/web
WORKDIR /usr/src/web
COPY package.json /usr/src/web
COPY ./src /user/src/web
COPY .npmrc /usr/src/web

RUN yarn
RUN rm -f .npmrc

COPY . /usr/src/web

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

**package.json:**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -L --experimental-json-modules --no-warnings server.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod --watch"
  }
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is to create a developmental environment using docker, wsl2, node, angular, and express. I'm fairly new to docker so I don't really know what I'm doing. However when I build and run everything, there is a problem. Nodemon detects all changes made from my source folder EXPECT the /src file inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

So the method I'm trying to use would not work even if I didn't try using docker. So I'm not sure why I thought it would work with docker. What I did to work around this was create two separate services to handle the building/serving of the website.

I changed my docker-compose file to this

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
    web-build:
        build: ./web
        command: sh -c "yarn; yarn run build"
        working_dir: /usr/src/web
        volumes:
            - ./web:/usr/src/web:cached
    web-serve:
        build: ./web
        command: sh -c "yarn; yarn start"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./web:/usr/src/web:cached
```

I stopped using nodemon as just calling --watch on ng build was sufficient. Something I noticed though was that there is a delay when updating the source files to server